# Using authblk package automated count on affil command

Tags: titles, affiliation, authblk

My current coding is affiliation link number insert manually.

```
    \title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[3]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{address one}
\affil[2]{address two}
\affil[3]{address three}
```

But i want affiliation link number to be entered automatically like counter concept.suggest solution

For Example:

```
\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}
    \author[1]{Junli Liu}
    \author[2]{James Rowe}
    \author[3]{Keith Lindsey}
    \affil{address one}
    \affil{address two}
    \affil{address three}
```

[image]

Comment: You've *completely* changed the question, from requesting no affiliation enumeration to automatic numbering. My suggestion is to *not* do this, since it makes existing answers completely void. Rather [ask a new, follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what logic you're expecting in `\affil`.

There are two forms for using `authblk` facilities.

### First form

```
\author{Name1}
\affil{Affiliation1}

\author{Name2a}
\author{Name2b}
\affil{Affiliation 2}
```

(any number of authors can precede an `\affil` command, that will refer to that group of authors). It's your case:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}

\author{Junli Liu}
\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences,
  The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}

\author{James Rowe}
\author{Keith Lindsey}
\affil{Some other laboratory, Elsewhere}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

### Second form

If affiliations don't follow the order of authors, one has to go with the second form, where the optional argument becomes necessary:

```
\author[1]{Name1a}
\author[2]{Name2}
\author[1]{Name1b}

\affil[1]{Affiliation1}
\affil[2]{Affiliation2}
```

So, if in your case Lindsey has the same affiliation as Liu, you should input

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}

\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[1]{Keith Lindsey}

\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences,
  The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil[2]{Some other laboratory, Elsewhere}

\maketitle
```

and you'd get

[image]

### Alternative way

If you have an affiliation for each author and want automatic numbering, you can do it by changing how the commands work.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\usepackage{letltxmacro,xpatch}
\newcounter{affiliations}
\LetLtxMacro{\authblkauthor}{\author}
\LetLtxMacro{\authblkaffil}{\affil}

\renewcommand{\author}[1]{%
  \authblkauthor[\theauthors]{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\affil}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{affiliations}%
  \authblkaffil[\theaffiliations]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}

\author{Junli Liu}
\author{James Rowe}
\author{Keith Lindsey}

\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences,
  The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil{Some other laboratory, Elsewhere}
\affil{Another laboratory, Somewhere Else}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you'd get exactly the same result by using the first form, which in my opinion is clearer input.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}

\author{Junli Liu}
\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences,
  The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}

\author{James Rowe}
\affil{Some other laboratory, Elsewhere}

\author{Keith Lindsey}
\affil{Another laboratory, Somewhere Else}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Another possibility (here you need the optional argument next to `\author`):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\usepackage{letltxmacro,xpatch}
\newcounter{affiliations}
\LetLtxMacro{\authblkaffil}{\affil}

\renewcommand{\affil}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{affiliations}%
  \authblkaffil[\theaffiliations]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}

\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[3]{Keith Lindsey}

\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences,
  The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil{Some other laboratory, Elsewhere}
\affil{Another laboratory, Somewhere Else}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not giving any optional arguments like "\affil[1]"

Comment: I am not giving any optional arguments like "\affil[1]" I am giving only "\affil{text here}". If the only one affil is there the number is "1" is not shown "address one". More than one affil is given the number is automatically counted like "1 address one, 2 address two".. I would like to work this logic auto counting

Comment: @SaravanakkhumarC Please, add some clarifications (and examples) to your question.

Comment: I edit and save my clarification. Suggest your solution.

Comment: @Vetri I added the code, but for that application I think the first form is better, because in this way the affiliation is immediately input after the relative author.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one entry to not have a number, you could use `\affil[ ]{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil[$\relax$]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

If you want all `\affil` to be void of numbers you can add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\let\oldaffil\affil% Store a copy of \affil in \oldaffil
\renewcommand{\affil}{\oldaffil[ ]}% Update \affil to *always* use \affil[ ]
```

The above modification makes `\affil` default to `\affil[ ]` so you don't have to pass an optional argument anymore.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\let\oldaffil\affil
\renewcommand{\affil}{\oldaffil[ ]}
\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development: a combined experimental and modeling perspective}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\affil{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\null$`? Really? ;-)

Comment: @egreg: It's makes logically sense to have no/`\null` affiliation. Being `\relax`ed about it is just as good.

Comment: No, `\relax` wouldn't work, because the command does `\if\relax#1\relax`. Neither `\null` would work, because `\if` would compare `\relax` and `\hbox`. Simpler: `\affil[ ]`. The test should be `\ifx\hfuzz#1\hfuzz`, of course (any primitive not expected in the argument would be good as well).