# Using authblk package for acmart class

Tags: acm, author-number, authblk

I use `\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}` class. I want to use `\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}` package but it seems it does not work unless if I moved to `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`, based on this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219568/using-authblk-package-automated-count-on-affil-command). I think I can disable the function that handles authors' view in `acmart.cls` but I am not sure in which line!! Has anyone faced such an issue before?

Thank you

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488928/acm-authors-with-multiple-affiliations/489065

Answer (score 1):

`acmart` uses its own mechanism to format authors' block according to ACM specifications and requirements.  It is not compatible with `authblk`.  This is a feature, not a bug:  ACM does not want you to change the way you format title page.