# ACM authors with multiple affiliations

Tags: acm, author, affiliation

I am trying to use **authblk** package. However, when I use it, all the authors just disappear! I deleted all my authors and copied complete examples which had used **authblk** but the same thing happened. Does anyone know what's the matter? Any other solution for multiple affiliations?
[image: this is what I get]

```
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{More than one Author with different Affiliations}
\author[1]{Author A}
\author[1]{Author B}
\author[1]{Author C}
\author[2]{Author D}
\author[2]{Author E}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example code?

Comment: @JouleV I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

ACM uses its own scheme for grouping authors, which is not compatible with `authblk`.

Please use this syntax:

```
\author{Author A}
\author{Author B}
\author{Author C}
\affiliation{\institution{\LaTeX\ University}
             \department{Department of Computer Science}}
\author{Author D}
\author{Author E}
\affiliation{\institution{\LaTeX\ University}
             \department{Department of Mechanical Engineering}}
```

Comment: It is correct. However, if A and C have the same affiliation while B and D have another, this solution will end up in 4 times affiliation!

Comment: Well, this is how ACM wants it...